# Reading a file that keeps getting overwritten and get the differences with the previous

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I'm writing a python script that has to monitor a file for data, parse it and push it into a Redis queue. The source of this data is a file that get overwritten with new data every minute.

The original file is a log file that reside in a different (inaccessible) machine. A script copy the original file and send it to my machine, completely overriding the previous one. I cannot change this behavior and have to work around it.
From this file I have to recognize the last log lines (after the ones I read in the previous cycle) and parse them.

Is there a way to do this easily in python?
My idea was to use watchdog to recognize when the file was overwritten, access it, seek the previous position and keep reading from there.
Still, I don't know what would happen if the file gets overwritten while I'm reading it. Also there may be an easier way.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: @martineau . Sorry, that wasn't my intention. I'm not expecting code as an answer. Still, do you think I'm approaching it the right way? Do you think that saving the "seek position" and accessing it again when watchdog notice an overwrite is a good way or there is a better solution to do this.
If this seems like I'm asking others to do things for me I'll just delete the post.

Comment: Offhand your scheme sounds like it might work especially if the files are just increasing in size by have more data written to them at the end. As for what happens in the case of an overwrite, I suspect you'll have to find that out for yourself by testing it (i.e. research the topic).

Comment: @martineau . Thank you. I'll do some tests then. After your comments and rereading my question, it actually sound like one just searching for approval. I'll try to ask better questions in the future.